# iOS 7 Using HW Volume buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I was looking for a way to handle a custom callback when the user presses the HW volume buttons when they are within my application.

I have been looking around for a solution but can't seem to find one that will work in iOS 7 SDK. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is against the guidelines and even if you do find a way your app will probably be rejected.

Comment: this app I am making is currently just for collecting data and will not be submitted. Using the volume button to start this process is preferred in my test cases unfortunately...might have to find a hacky way around it...